Debugging with LLDB over SSH "error: process exited with status -1 (no such process.)" MacOS
I'm trying to debug an executable, that I manually built with clang, with lldb on MacOS host (ssh'd into) machine, through ssh. However, when I run it I get:

(lldb) error: process exited with status -1 (no such process.)

If I try the same with system executable like /bin/ls it works, perhaps because they are signed by Apple. My executable isn't signed so I tried self-signing it but no luck.
Experimenting more, I copied /bin/ls and resigned it with my own self-sign certificate which led to the same problem again! So, I believe this might be something to do with signing.
Other things that I have tried:

Self-sign the executable. Followed instructions here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html.
Add entitlements following Xcode lldb can't attach to MacOS system program /bin/cp - "Not allowed to attach to process.".
Run lldb with sudo.
sudo DevToolsSecurity --enable
spctl developer-mode enable-terminal

Why do the system executables work but not mine?
System details:

Darwin 23.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.4.0: arm64
macOS 14: Sonoma

NOTE: I have checked other answers. This one lldb gives error "error: process exited with status -1 (Error 1)" comes close but is unresolved as seen in the follow up comments on the top answer.

EDIT 1:
Dug more and generated logs. For the executable copied from /bin/ls the debugger is successful in attaching to it
[LaunchAttach] (93085) about to task_for_pid(93084)
108 +0.029169 sec [16b9d/0103]: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0203, pid = 93084, &task ) => err = 0x00000000 (success) err = 0x00000000
[LaunchAttach] (93085) successfully task_for_pid(93084)'ed

but for my own executable it fails
[LaunchAttach] (93825) about to task_for_pid(93824)
error: [LaunchAttach] MachTask::TaskPortForProcessID task_for_pid(93824) failed: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0203, pid = 93824, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure)
109 +0.027093 sec [16e81/0103]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0203, pid = 93824, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) err = ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0203, pid = 93824, &task ) => err = 0x00000005 ((os/kern) failure) (0x00000005)

Both executables are in the same directory.

EDIT 2: More info.
I compiled a simple example (default console app examples) with Xcode and here's what I found experimenting with it.
ssh + lldb fails to get the task only when all of the following is true:

executable is a x86_64 build. ARM build doesn't show the weird behavior.
The executable is on a NFS filesystem mount (nfs, nodev, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse). If it's on a "normal" filesystem (apfs, NFS exported, local, journaled, nobrowse, protect, root data) somehow it works.

NOTE: If either is not true, the debugging works. For e.g. I can debug the same code on the NFS filesystem mount when compiled for ARM architecture.
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
  return 0;
}

The exe build by Xcode is signed and has the following entitlements.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>com.apple.application-identifier</key><string></string><key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key><true/></dict></plist>


Did you make sure that your process runs remotely from your ssh-terminal session to the remote machine outside the debugger?

Yes, it does. @JimIngham

@JimIngham Generated logs and added to the question. Does that ring any bell?

The way this process works is lldb makes a kernel call saying "can I please have the task port for this process".  That gets relayed by the kernel to a daemon that is walled off from debugserver for security reasons.  That allows or denies the request, but all debugserver hears back is "yup" or "nope".  Again, that's by design since debugserver shouldn't be able to act on this.  Often if you look in the console log around where we were told "nope" some other system component will have left a log message saying why it rejected this.

In general, for a process to be debuggable, it has to be at least ad hoc codesigned  and if it has any entitlements or requirements it also has to have the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement set to the value true.  If you built this with Xcode using the Debug configuration it will do that for you automatically.  Otherwise you'll have to add this entitlement as part of your build.

Right, I signed it with a trusted cert and provided entitlements <key>com.apple.security.get-task-allow</key> <true/>. That's not enough. :(
What perplexes me is that there no entitlements on the executables in /bin (eg /bin/ls copy I made) but those are allowed to be fetched by the debugserver.

Can you provide a minimal complete example, so that other people can try ?

@Philippe I built the default example code in Xcode i.e. "Hello World!". Added more details after experimenting with it. It's a combination of x86_64 arch + NFS filesystem + ssh lldb that causes the issue.

Maybe try doing arch -x86_64 lldb -p <PID>...

@l'L'l No luck.
